# ItemsControl Binding to a DataModel.ObservableCollection

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, itemscontrol

I have a view (MainPage.xaml) which is bound to a ViewModel.
In the ViewModel I have a DataModel property (note that both viewmodel & datamodel implements INotifyPropertyChanged, or what that interface is called).

In my view i have defined an ItemsControl whose ItemsSource is bound to the said property. This property (DataModel) has an ObservableCollection (which i know it populated with valid data).

The xaml snippet looks like this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CurrentDataModel.Items}">
```

Note that i am not showing the rest of the xaml. All it shows is the ItemsTemplate which is just a TextBlock.

The issue is that nothing is being drawn for this ItemsControl, even though i can clearly see (while debugging) that the collection has good data.

Is this "Path=..." binding not possible for an ItemsControl's ItemsSource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Path syntax looks correct. The most likely cause of failure is that either the `DataContext` is not set to your `ViewModel` or that the property path you specified is incorrect.

In your question you state that the `ViewModel` has a property named DataModel but in the xaml snippet you have `CurrentDataModel`.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I failed to mentioned that other properties bound to the DataModel are showing up. For example, im displaying the number of items in the ItemsSource collection. This shows up (there are 3 items). But again, the itemscontrol itself does not render these 3 items.